# multiple if statements in excel 2010 version

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i am having trouble with using multiple if statements in excel.

```
=If(A1="something"|"something"|"n/a")  
=If(A1="nothing"|"nothing"|"no")
```

When used individually, they work but i am getting formula errors when i try to combine these two statements.

```
ex1:=If(A1="something"|"something"|"n/a"),If(A1="nothing"|"nothing"|"no")  
ex2:=If(A1="something","something","n/a",If(A1="nothing","nothing","no"))
```

I have looked at few threads on SO and I noticed that the argument separator is ',' but for some reason it only works with '|' (pipe)
I am using excel 2010.

Comment: Ex1 is not a valid expression. Too many parameters in ex2. Remove the "n/a".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check your region settings? I thing you have "**|**" configured as list separator. if you want to fix that go to **Control Panel** then click on **Clock, Language, and Region** then on **Region**

Once there go to **Additional settings...**

and change **List separator** to "**,**"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have side by side if statements, which will not work. Instead, you need to nest them, like this:

```
=IF(A1="something","something",IF(A1="nothing","nothing","no"))
```

This way, if A1 is "something" it will return "something", if it is "nothing" it will return "nothing", otherwise it will return "no". Also, this does not work with the pipe separator, only the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure precisely what you are trying to accomplish here... but perhaps a quick lesson will help.

An `IF` statement in Excel is of the form:

```
= IF(<condition>,<output if condition is TRUE>,<output if condition is FALSE>)
```

As far as separating arguments with `|` instead of `,`, I have never heard of this. I do know that some non-English versions of Excel use `;` as argument separators rather than `,` but I've never heard of `|` for this.

Going back to your examples,

```
= IF(A1="something","something","n/a")
```

This will return `something` if `A1` is exactly the text `something`, and will return `n/a` otherwise.

```
= IF(A1="nothing","nothing","no")
```

This will return `nothing` if `A1` is exactly the text `nothing`, and will return `no` otherwise.

Your formula:

```
= IF(A1="something","something","n/a",IF(A1="nothing","nothing","no"))
```

Is invalid Excel syntax because the first `IF` statement contains four arguments instead of three, which will result in an error.

*Perhaps* what you are trying to accomplish is this: (I don't know for sure because I don't know exactly what you mean when you say "*combine statements*"):

```
= IF(A1="something","something",IF(A1="nothing","nothing","no"))
```

This will return `something` if `A1` is exactly the text `something`, will return `nothing` if `A1` is exactly the text `nothing`, and will return `no` otherwise.

Comment: I apologize if the question was confusing. i relatively new to this community and i was not sure how to word it properly.
basically im trying to parse out a value(lengthy static string) in colA and print a short description in colb using if statement. i should not have used combine statements and instead use nested IF. i tried using your statement, it still gives me the same error as before "the formula you typed contains an error"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally got it to work.The problem is still with the ',' vs '|'.
i tried all of the answers above and it only works if i replace the , with the |.
i did try the same formula on Excel 2013 version and it works with ',' argument separator.

this is how it works now.

= IF(A1="something"|"something"|IF(A1="nothing"|"nothing"|"no"))

Thanks everyone for the feedback and i am sorry for posting a poorly written question.

Comment: This is not how you accept an answer. Please accept one of these answers by placing a checkmark next to it.